# Recovering photos from internally formatted SD card

Tags: data-recovery, internal-sd

All of a sudden my internally formatted SDCard in Android 6 stopped being recognized.  I'd done all the usual things, checked pin connections, checked it for errors, but nothing recognized it, so I ended up forgetting the card and I put in another SDCard as this one likely has errors.

Windows still recognizes it as a valid SDCard and shows the usual Android and LOST.dir but of course no data is available.

Is there away to recover photos from it?

Comment: You can apply the same technique as described here for a USB key: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288136/84179

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how a standard "internally formatted" sdcard is partitioned, but it is possible that photos are stored on an alternate partition not automatically mounted by Windows.

From the Windows Disk Management snap-in you can examine the partition structure of that disk (run <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and type `diskmgmt.msc`).

If the mounted partition is the only partition available on that disk you should make a backup image and perform recovery on that image.

If you suspect that the partition table may have been modified by you or some program you can use a tool like [testdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk) to examine and potentially recover previous partition structure.

To recover files I would recommend [foremost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foremost_(software)) (for Linux) or [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (for multiple platforms).